# How does one update scrollHeight after appending elements to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a div containing several images, with the overflow hidden, which slowly scrolls down.  I would like, when the scroll gets to the bottom, to clone the first element and append it to the bottom, so it will continue scrolling.

All this so far I have accomplished, except it doesn't keep scrolling, because the scrollHeight property is still the original value.  Is there any way to update the scrollHeight value of the div?

My script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#carousel").scrollTop(0);
intervalID = setInterval("scrollCarousel()",50);

carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
});

function scrollCarousel() {


if ( $("#carousel").scrollTop() > $("#carousel:first").height() ||
        $("#carousel").scrollTop() + carousel.offsetHeight >
        carousel.scrollHeight ) {

    elem = $("#carousel").children(':first-child').clone();
    console.debug(elem);
    elem.appendTo($("#carousel"));
    carousel.scrollHeight += elem.height;
}
else {
    $("#carousel").scrollTop( $("#carousel").scrollTop() + 1 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/bPrY7/

You had a few mistakes:

First of all you shouldn't put a string in setInterval. Especially when you are just calling a function. Since strings get parsed by eval they are quite slow.

Secondly you want to remove the element from the top when you append it to the bottom, and then just adjust the scroll position accordingly.

Also $("#carousel") is a lot slower than $(carousel) when you already have the DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  Unfortunately, when it gets to the bottom of the scrollHeight, it starts moving the first child to the end, but since the scroll position is the same it just keeps doing this without scrolling.

Comment: Ah, I just forgot to set the scrollTop to 0 after moving the image.  Problem solved!

Comment: @Zack Michener If you're interested, I remade it without jQuery. 

The original is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/bPrY7/16/

The new one which doesn't need jQuery is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/bPrY7/

Comment: Strings in setInterval should mainly be avoided for correctness reasons; performance is secondary. Eval'ing strings is bad practice, because the interpreter cannot do static analysis on the code until it reaches the point of execution, which eliminated many of its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea, if you can put the first child at the end of the carousel statically, you can avoid the clone and therefore the problem.

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: Well the idea is, whenever it scrolls to the bottom it tacks more on to the end, so it scrolls infinitely.